# How do I calculate the total of multiple items?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a total of price of all the items multiplied by the quantity of the item:

```
const shoppingCart = {
    "tax": .08,
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "orange juice",
            "price": 3.99,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "title": "rice",
            "price": 1.99,
            "quantity": 3
```

The result I want to get is 9.96. But I'm struggling to come up with a proper way to do so.

Comment: Loop over `shoppingCary.items` array and then add the price as `price * quantity`. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a for loop

```
let totalPrice = 0

shoppingCart.items.forEach(item => {
  totalPrice += item.price * item.quantity
})
```

But in JS it's also useful to get used to different iterators such as [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). It may appear a bit confusing at first but basically it just loops through the array, applies some logic (that we can add) and returns a single value which is perfect for computing sum.

```
const totalPrice = shoppingCart.items.reduce((total, item) => total + (item.price * item.quantity), 0)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thats exactly what i was trying to think of! Thank you